# Using FirestoreErrors in Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, type-safety

How can I use the [FirestoreError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) class in my Firebase cloud functions?

I want to throw errors of type FirestoreError when the document or field I am looking for is undefined in Firestore:

```
throw new FirestoreError();
```

When I import FirestoreError like this: `import { FirestoreError } from "firebase/firestore";` and throw a FirestoreError, it says that the constructor is private. Can I throw a FirestoreError from a Firebase function or will I have to throw an HttpsError?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`FirestoreError` is an internal, technical error.

I guess you want to throw an *AppError* which does relate to your Apps logic and not to a technical problem with Firestore itself.

And for this one may use an `HttpsError`. Catch it in the client side and check `your-app-error-id`.

```
throw functions.https.HttpsError(
  'your-app-error-id',
  'The message.'
);
```

**Docs**

> **To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
> callable by throwing ... an
> instance of functions.https.HttpsError.**
>
> If an error other than HttpsError is thrown from your functions, your
> client instead receives an error with the message INTERNAL and the
> code internal.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

**Example**

```
if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
      'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Is it generally good practice to send an HttpsError for all errors that have to do with application logic or invalid inputs?

Comment: @MatthewKeller Yes, see the updated answer.